# Как можно объединить mysql запрос?

Tags: mysql

Объединить 3 запроса в 1 возможно? А то сейчас приходится делать 3 через php

1. Получаем список `item_id` из таблицы `items_all`

   ```
   SELECT `item_id` FROM `items_all` WHERE 1
   ```
2. По списку `item_id` получаем среднюю стоимость для каждого во второй таблице

   ```
   SELECT `id_item`,(sum(`price_item`)/count(*)) as aver_price FROM `l2_trader` WHERE `id_item`='{Полученный ранее список item_id}'
   ```
3. Обновить данные в `items_all` столбец `aver`

   ```
   UPDATE `items_all` SET `aver`=aver_price WHERE `item_id`={Полученный ранее список id}
   ```

Скорее всего через объединение надо делать но что то я немогу

```
UPDATE `items_all` as table1 
INNER JOIN(

    SELECT (sum(`price_item`)/count(*)) as aver_price FROM `l2_trader` WHERE `id_item`=table1.`item_id`) as table2 USING(`item_id`)

SET table1.`aver`=table2.aver_price
```

Comment: А зачем вам WHERE 1 в первом запросе?

Comment: Добавил в первый пост

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'table1.item_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: не видит `id_item`=table1.item_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Честно говоря у вас запросы не совсем рабочие те, что вы написали. Вот это не то, что вам нужно?

```
UPDATE items_all ia SET aver = (SELECT sum(price_item)/count(*) FROM l2_trader lt WHERE lt.id_item = ia.item_id)
```

Comment: Именно то что надо, я и не знал что такой запрос можно формировать. 

Еще для себя увидел что, "as" можно не использовать.
Спасибо.